# Attach multiple image formats, not just JPG to email

Tags: image, email, png, email-attachments

This is what i have so far...

```
 MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream();
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fuImage.PostedFile.InputStream);
        string filename = fuImage.PostedFile.FileName;

        img.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        imgStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        EmailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(imgStream, filename, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg));
```

So it attaches a JPEG image fine. But i want to change it so that it allows PNG's and GIFs.

Comment: .... did you try `.Gif`?

Comment: explain? i want it to allow me to attach Jpg, Gif or Png

Answer (score 4):

You've probably have found this answer by now, so this answer is for anyone else who runs into this issue.

```
    Image image = ConvertToImage(response);
    Stream imageStream = ToStream(image, ImageFormat.Png);
    LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(imageStream, "image/png");
```

Above is a sample worked for me, ConvertToImage returns System.Drawing.Image and ToStream returns System.IO.Stream.

I hope this helps!

Comment: _ToStream returns System.IO.Stream_ Where does it come from?

Comment: This was answered this back in 2013 and worked for me then, I cant say for sure if it still work as I  no longer have the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.imageUpload.PostedFile.FileName);

 string low = ext.ToLower();

 MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream();

                System.Drawing.Image theImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageUpload.PostedFile.InputStream);

                string filename = imageUpload.PostedFile.FileName;

              if (low == ".jpg")
                {
                    theImage.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                }
                else if (low == ".gif")
                {
                    theImage.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                }
                else if (low == ".tif")
                {
                    theImage.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
                }

            imgStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                if (low == ".jpg")
                {

                    mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(imgStream, filename, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg));
                }

                else if (low == ".gif")
                {

                    mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(imgStream, filename, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif));
                }

 else if (low == ".tif")
                {

                    mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(imgStream, filename, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Tiff));
                }
```

doing .png seems a little trickier, but at least that's on the right track.

Comment: hi..i want to attach multiple images with email in bb, is it possible?